# Call custom phtml in homepage

Tags: phtml

I am new in magento. i m using magento version `1.9.0.1`

I want to call custom phtml in homepage using my custom module. i don't want to change in CMS pages.

How can i do this?

Comment: David explained that very nice here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/21573/231

Comment: You can use the Layout XML + <cms_index_index> handle.

Comment: Just call phtml file from cms home page in magento admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have created a block you can add it to the homepage using this in your theme xml or if you have a layout xml file in your module drop it in there.

```
  <cms_index_index>
      <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name=""your_template" template="your_template.phtml" />
      </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```